# Iterate over a list to update PySpark df column

Tags: python, list, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, iteration

Need to add a new column to PySpark DF based on conditions by iterating over a list.

```py
new_line_id = array('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Input DF (*`LineID` is not the PK in this DF*):

| Line ID |
| --- |
| M |
| null |
| T |
| null |
| null |
| P |

The list contains exactly as many items as number of Null in the Line ID. Basically whenever the `LineID` is null, pick a value from the List.

Required Output:

| Line ID | New Column |
| --- | --- |
| M | M |
| null | a |
| T | T |
| null | b |
| null | c |
| P | P |

The following code adds the whole list in each row. but, it doesn't work.

```py
new_df = df.withColumn("new_col", when(df.line_id.isNull(), array([lit(x) for x in new_line_id]).cast(StringType()).otherwise(df.line_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, when, col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df.show()

windowSpec = Window.orderBy(col("LineID")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

df_with_row_num = df.withColumn("row_num", when(col("LineID").isNull(), row_number().over(windowSpec)).otherwise(None))

def assign_value(line_id, row_num):
    if line_id is None:
        return new_line_id[row_num - 1] # subtract 1 because Python list indexing starts at 0
    else:
        return line_id

assign_value_udf = udf(assign_value, StringType())

new_df = df_with_row_num.withColumn("new_col", assign_value_udf(col("LineID"), col("row_num")))

new_df.show()
```